# Update variable by observer Angular/Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subject

Here is my code:

UtilisateursService.ts

```
public AllUsers:Utilisateur[]=[{ UserId:'',firstName:'', lastName:'',email:'',phoneNumber:null,roles:'',active:"false",createdBy:'',createdDate:null,lastModifiedBy:'',lastModifiedDate:null,},];

  **public userSubject = new Subject<Utilisateur[]>();**
  //userSubject2 = new Subject<Classe[]>();

  emitUsers(u:Utilisateur[]) {
    this.userSubject.next(u.slice());
        }


getAllUsers() {

           var childsdata:Utilisateur[]=[];
           firebase.database().ref("/users").orderByKey().once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
               snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                 childsdata.push(childSnapshot.val());
             });
           });

           this.AllUsers=childsdata;
            this.emitUsers(this.AllUsers);

           console.log("this.AllUsers = ",this.AllUsers);

  };
```

ListeUtilisateursComponent.ts

```
export class ListeUtilisateursComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
  // users: Utilisateur[];
  usersSubscription: Subscription;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['nom', 'prenom', 'email', 'role','active','actions'];
  **UserdataSource;**

  constructor(private usersService: UtilisateursService,private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.usersService.userSubject.subscribe((AllUsers) => {
      **this.UserdataSource = AllUsers;**
    });


    this.usersService.getAllUsers();


    // this.UserdataSource=this.usersService.getAllUsers();
    console.log("Dans ngOnInit, this.UserdataSource ==== ",this.UserdataSource);

  }
```

ListeUtilisateursComponent.html

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="*UserdataSource*" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="nom">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nom </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.lastName}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="prenom">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Prénom </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.firstName}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Email </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.email}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

the variable AllUsers of UtilisateurService updates correctly
The variable UserdataSource is always empty, it seems that the observer doesn't work. 
Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put them inside your request. this is async call your data may still not fill while you try outside of request

```
 getAllUsers() {
  var that=this;
  var childsdata:Utilisateur[]=[];
  firebase.database().ref("/users").orderByKey().once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
           childsdata.push(childSnapshot.val());
           that.AllUsers=childsdata;
           that.emitUsers(that.AllUsers);
            console.log("that.AllUsers = ",that.AllUsers);
         });
      });
 };
```

Comment: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'AllUsers' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property 'AllUsers' of undefined . See my comment for the complete error

Comment: You're welcome :) It says undefined because 'this' is related to function(childSnapshot) in foreach so, we changed service 's 'this' to that

Answer (score 0):

There are issues in service and the component. In both cases, asynchronous data is accessed synchronously.

#### Service

`childsdata` is assigned asynchronously, so `this.AllUsers = childsdata;` statement and other statments that depend on `this.AllUsers` should be within the `then` enclosure.

And to access member variables inside callbacks, functions defined with `function` keyword should be replaced with arrow functions. The meaning of `this` keyword in a traditional JS function denotes the scope of the function and in an arrow function denotes the class.

More details on it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/6513921

```js
public AllUsers: Utilisateur[] = [{ UserId: '', firstName: '', lastName: '', email: '', phoneNumber: null, roles: '', active: "false", createdBy: '', createdDate: null, lastModifiedBy: '', lastModifiedDate: null},];

public userSubject = new Subject<Utilisateur[]>();

emitUsers(u: Utilisateur[]) {
  this.userSubject.next(u.slice());
}

getAllUsers() {
  let childsdata: Utilisateur[] = [];
  firebase.database().ref("/users").orderByKey().once("value").then((snapshot) => {    // <-- arrow function here
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {    // <-- arrow function here
        childsdata.push(childSnapshot.val());
        this.AllUsers = childsdata;
        this.emitUsers(this.AllUsers);
        console.log("this.AllUsers = ",this.AllUsers);
    });
  });
};
```

#### Component

`UserdataSource` is assigned asynchronously, so the console log that prints it should be within the subscription.

```js
export class ListeUtilisateursComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
  // users: Utilisateur[];
  usersSubscription: Subscription;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['nom', 'prenom', 'email', 'role','active','actions'];
  **UserdataSource;**

  constructor(private usersService: UtilisateursService,private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.usersService.userSubject.subscribe((AllUsers) => {
      this.UserdataSource = AllUsers;
      console.log("Dans ngOnInit, this.UserdataSource ==== ", this.UserdataSource);
    });
    this.usersService.getAllUsers();
  }
}
```

See here for more details on how to access asynchronous data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6513921